# Teamspeak 3 .sh file not running ubuntu 15.04

Tags: .sh, teamspeak

I have installed Teamspeak 3 using this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92G6KYdlCRc.

Once I try to run the .sh file nothing happens. I try to run it in terminal same thing.

I made the file executable and changed the setting to ask me how to run executable files.

Could someone please help?

Comment: you shouldn't have to make the file executable, it already is. just click and drag it into a terminal and press enter. you do not need to type sh before doing so because it's actually a bash file and not sh script anyhow.

Comment: Just tried what you said and same thing happened. It asked me what I wanted to do: run, run in terminal, cancel. When I click "run" or "run in terminal" nothing happens

Comment: *update* After dragging the file into the terminal and selecting "run" and nothing happened, I hit enter again then this error appeared "/home/sean/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh: line 16: ./ts3client_linux_amd64: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: BTW if you are using a 64 bit machine, you can install the amd64 version of ubuntu even if it is intel if you would like to use the 64 bit version of ubuntu. i386 is 32bit.

Comment: Okay, I've included a step by step that will get the 32 bit teamspeak up and running in 3 simple commands.

Comment: Im pretty new to linux and im ganna be honest and say I thought I did download the 64 bit. I just did terminal comman uname -a and found out im 32 bit. Ganna make a new post to install 64 bit ubuntu from inside 32bit ubuntu

Comment: Just to let you know, the youtube guide youre refering to is private so it cant be watched :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error is common when trying to run a 64 bit application on a 32 bit (x86 or i386) version of linux

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

So it seems you have the 32bit (i386) version of Ubuntu and you are trying to run 64bit teamspeak. Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

First command will download the 32 bit (x86) version to your home folder:

```
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.16/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.16.run
```

Next command will run the run file:

```
sh TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.16.run
```

Finally, after you accept the user agreement, run the following command to start teamspeak:

```
~/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86/ts3client_runscript.sh
```

Please post any errors, thanks!