# Teamspeak Client will not install on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, teamspeak

Can someone please explain how to search for an application within the shell when apt-get doesn't work. I am currently in a situation where I cannot find the package I want, but now I am stuck with what to do.

```
$ sudo apt-get install teamspeak-client 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package teamspeak-client
```

Can someone also explain how to copy large blocks of shell commands into this editor and make it format properly. I'm not indenting every line of commands by 4 spaces every time.

Comment: When you write a question, there should be a line above text field, where you see formatting options, bold, italic, hyperlink, etc. Curly braces are for code blocks. Highlight the chunk of text you want and press those curly braces. Simple enough, right? :D

Answer (score 2):

Searching teamspeak in the repositories with `apt-cache search teamspeak` reveals that indeed, teamspeak cannot be found, hence not available for download in Ubuntu repositories, but you can download it from official teamspeak website: http://www.teamspeak.com/?page=downloads

If you have AMD cpu, select amd package. For others - Client X86.

You will be prompted to download a `.run` file, which is somewhat equivalent of `.exe` file in windows. Once it's done, open terminal, make the file executable with `sudo chmod +x filename.run` , and then `./filename.run` to launch the installation

Comment: If you like my answer, leave me an upvote ^ . Solved your problem ? Click the grey checkmark sign to accept the answer

Comment: Ok. Just 1 more question. Another guy on the forum said to install apps in your home directory. Is that also your recommendation too? I am a Linux noob so I don't know.

Comment: Apps by default go to `/usr/bin` directory, which is how it should be. Did the guy say why would you want to install it in home directory ?

Comment: No he was probably just less experienced in Linux maybe. Ok I run that file, and extracted it to /usr/bin/ . So now I have a folder in there called TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64. Fine The program also works, great! So now I want to know how to make a shortcut that I can use on the toolbar on the left of my screen so that I can just launch it quickly? As currently I would have to type cd /usr/bin/[my username]/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64, then ./ts3client_runscript.sh. Which is the definition of a ball-ache.

Comment: You can still use the 64 bit download with an intel processor so long it is 64bit (tested on a core i3)

Comment: @johnsmith You can open file manager in that folder , then right click and `Make a link ` to that script. Then place that link on your desktop. Basically that's the same as making shortcut in Windows. Not sure if the link can be pinned to the launcher. I'd have to switch to Unity in a minute, as right now I am using Gnome desktop environment

Comment: I'd prefer this method, though : [How to add a shell script to launcher](http://askubuntu.com/q/141229/295286)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this can be a lifesaver. To search using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-cache search teamspeak
```

To narrow the results, use grep like so:

```
sudo apt-cache search teamspeak | grep team
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's available through apt-get but [you can easily install it; see my teamspeak installation answer here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/626825/167115) The instructions are for a 32bit (i386) but to install the 64bit version you just have to download the other package available [here.](http://www.teamspeak.com/?page=downloads)